# Writing a for loop that iterates through filenames in a text file

Tags: beamer, loops, external-files, for-loop

I would like to create beamer slides where each slide contains an image. I have a file that contains a list of all the image locations.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Import necessary packages
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Set beamer theme and color scheme
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

% Define title and author
\title{PDF Slides}
\author{Your Name}

\begin{document}

% Title slide
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

% Read list of PDF file names from text file
\newread\file
\openin\file=fileloop.txt
\loop
    \read\file to\fileline
    \unless\ifeof\file
        % Remove trailing newline character from file name
        \edef\fileline{\expandafter\stripnewline\fileline}
        % Create slide with PDF image for current file
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{\fileline}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight, width=0.8\textwidth]{\fileline}
        \end{frame}
    \repeat
\closein\file

\end{document}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Extra }, or forgotten $.
> Undefined control sequence.
> Missing } inserted.
> Missing $ inserted.

The error is for the `\repeat`
I checked and there was nothing not closed. What is the correct way to use `\repeat`?

Edit:

fileloop.txt looks like this:

```
file_1.pdf
file_2.pdf
file_3.pdf
```

All files are in the same folder as the latex script. They are listed one file per line and not comma separated. There are underscores in the file names. I'm not sure if that is causing a problem.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Can you show a short example of how your fileloop.tex file looks like?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added the file in an edit.

Comment: I tried removing the underscores from the file names and still the same error.

Comment: @Michal The problem seems to be that `\stripnewline` is undefined. Where did you find that command?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I saw this line of code in an example on overleaf.

Comment: @Michal Do you still have the link so we can see how it is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `expl3`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.lst}
example-image-a
example-image-b
example-image-c
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}

% Set beamer theme and color scheme
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

%% boilerplate code for image inclusion from a file
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\dofromfile}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = template
  \michal_read_do:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_michal_read_ior

\cs_new_protected:Nn \michal_read_do:nn
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_michal_read_ior { #1 }
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_michal_read_ior { #2 }
  \ior_close:N \g_michal_read_ior
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Define title and author
\title{PDF Slides}
\author{Your Name}

\begin{document}

% Title slide
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\dofromfile{\jobname.lst}{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\texttt{#1}}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight, width=0.8\textwidth]{#1}
  \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents` just to make the example self-contained.

In the second argument to `\dofromfile` you specify what you want to do with the current line of input from the file, denoting it with `#1`.

[image]

Comment: This may be an obvious question to you, but how do I prevent it from getting the error: ```must be inside math mode```? I imported the expl3 package.

Comment: Nevermind, it works even with the error. I accepted the answer